# HDMI is not giving an output "AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, monitor

I can't seem to get an output from my HDMI port, however I can access it through PuTTY. When I use `xrandr` I keep getting messages "Can't open display". Maybe there's an obvious error in the logs I can't quite seem to figure out as I'm not entirely experienced with Ubuntu.

"/var/log/Xorg.0.log" is the log below:

X11 log:

```
[   120.695] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-9026.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[   120.696] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[   120.696] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   120.696] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic aarch64 Ubuntu
[   120.696] Current Operating System: Linux tegra-ubuntu 4.14.102-rt53-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Sep 20 16:23:45 PDT 2019 aarch64
[   120.696] Kernel command line: fbcon=map:9 aurixfw=AFW root=/dev/vblkdev0p1 gpt rootwait ip=off rw gpt console=ttyS0,115200n8 tegra_keep_boot_clocks cma=536870912 disable_android_paranoid_network sdhci_tegra.en_boot_part_access=1  tegraid=19.1.2.0.0 uid=16420f1420000000008008280 bl_debug_data=65536@0x7ffffd0000 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0x0c280000 console=ttyS0,115200n8 bl_prof_dataptr=2048@0x7fb56b7000
[   120.696] Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:10:37PM
[   120.696] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   120.696] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   120.697]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   120.697] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   120.697] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Dec  1 09:59:08 2020
[   120.697] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   120.697] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   120.697] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   120.698] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   120.698] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[   120.698] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[   120.699] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[   120.699] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Tegra0"
[   120.699] (**) Option "BlankTime" "0"
[   120.699] (**) Option "StandbyTime" "0"
[   120.699] (**) Option "SuspendTime" "0"
[   120.699] (**) Option "OffTime" "0"
[   120.699] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   120.699] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   120.699] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   120.699] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   120.699] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   120.699] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   120.699]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   120.699] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   120.699]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   120.699] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   120.699]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   120.699] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   120.699]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   120.699] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   120.699]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   120.699] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   120.699] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/tegra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   120.699] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   120.699] (II) Loader magic: 0x556c1b3010
[   120.700] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   120.700]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   120.700]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   120.700]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   120.700]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   120.702] (++) using VT number 2

[   120.706] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_3235
[   120.709] (II) no primary bus or device found
[   120.710] (WW) "dri" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[   120.710] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   120.710] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[   120.710] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[   120.710] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   120.710] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   120.713] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.713]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.713]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   120.713] (II) LoadModule: "dummy"
[   120.714] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module dummy
[   120.714] (II) UnloadModule: "dummy"
[   120.714] (II) Unloading dummy
[   120.714] (EE) Failed to load module "dummy" (module does not exist, 0)
[   120.714] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   120.714] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   120.715] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   120.715]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.715]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   120.715] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   120.715] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   120.715] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   120.715] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   120.716] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   120.716] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.716]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[   120.716]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   120.716]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   120.716] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   120.717] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   120.717] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   120.717]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.717]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   120.717] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   120.717] (II) Unloading nvidia
[   120.717] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 0)
[   120.717] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   120.717] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   120.717] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.717]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[   120.718]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   120.718]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   120.718] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  425.00  Release Build  (integ_stage_rel)  (buildbrain@mobile-u64-3141)  Fri Sep 20 15:53:17 PDT 2019
[   120.718] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   120.718] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   120.718] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   120.718] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for NVIDIA
[   120.718] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   120.718] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   120.719] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   120.719] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.719]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.719]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   120.719] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   120.719] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   120.719] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   120.720] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.720]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.720]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   120.720] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   120.720] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   120.720] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   120.721] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   120.721] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   120.721] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   120.721] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   120.721] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   120.722] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   120.722] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.722]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[   120.722]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   120.722] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[   120.722] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   120.722] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   120.722] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   120.722] (II) UnloadSubModule: "wfb"
[   120.722] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
[   120.722] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   120.722] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   120.722] (II) UnloadSubModule: "wfb"
[   120.723] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
[   120.723] (**) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   120.723] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[   120.723] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   120.723] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   120.723] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: tegra_fb (video memory: 0kB)
[   120.723] (DB) xf86MergeOutputClassOptions unsupported bus type 0
[   120.723] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[   120.723] (II) FBDEV(0):     mode "1920x1080" ok
[   120.723] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[   120.723] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 0x0 (pitch 0)
[   120.723] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
[   120.723] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   120.723] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   120.723] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   120.724] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   120.724] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.724]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   120.724]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   120.724] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[   120.724] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[   120.724] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[   120.724] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[   120.725] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   120.725]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.1.0
[   120.725]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   120.725] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   120.725] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   120.725] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   120.725] (EE) FBDEV(0): mmap fbmem: Invalid argument
[   120.725] (EE) FBDEV(0): mapping of video memory failed
[   120.725] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   120.725] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
[   120.725] (EE) 
[   120.725] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   120.725] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   120.725] (EE) 
[   120.727] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Thanks!